# How to create powershell script to retry on error

Tags: powershell, while-loop

I am writing a Powershell script to copy unencrypted EBS Snapshots in AWS to Encrypted Snapshots. In AWS the max number of concurrent copies is currently 20 at one time, but I have 1400 snapshots to copy. I wrote a script in Powershell using a For Each loop to loop through the snapshot IDs stored in a Text file, and it works as expected until it gets to 20 snapshots being copied. Then it will throw the following error and fail:

```
An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CopySnapshot operation: Too many snapshot copies in progress. The limit is 20 for this destination region.
```

I have tried to use a While Do statement, but I believe I am missing some items on here. The script is listed below. Essentially I am trying to have it if the script gets to 20 concurrent copies, it will retry on the one snapshot until a free spot opens up and then move on to the next. Ideally I would like to just have this run in the background for a day or so. See the current script below:

```sh
function Get-TimeStamp {   
    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)    
}

$kmsID = "blah"
$region = "us-east-1"
$stoploop = $false
[int]$Retrycount = "0"

Foreach($line in get-content C:\snaps4.txt) {
    do {
        $desc = aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids $line | ConvertFrom-Json
        $description = $desc.Snapshots.Description
        Write-Output "$description"

        $snap = aws ec2 copy-snapshot --description "[Copied $line from us-east-1] $description" --source-region $region --source-snapshot-id $line --encrypted  --kms-key-id $kmsID | ConvertFrom-Json
        $newsnap = $snap.SnapshotId
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Created copy of $line $description with NEW SnapshotID $newsnap" >> C:\log.txt
        $stoploop = $true
    }
    While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions, and I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the copy command inside a try/catch block.
Something like this:

```
try {
  copy command; 
  mark as complete
} 
catch{
  mark as failed
}
```

one approach is to make the content file a csv with file name and complete columns.  Use import-csv to read it; iterate the imported list when `$_.complete -ne "Y"` and set complete to "Y" when it succeeds.  Export the file at the end.
Re-run as needed